# SSRS create hyperlink on report to aspx page of my application with some value as querystring.

Tags: hyperlink, reporting-services, drilldown

I want to send SSRS report field as querystring paramater to my application page. for this I have done following steps:

To add a hyperlink in report:

```
In report design view, right-click the text box I want to add a link and then click Properties.

1.In the Properties dialog box, click Action.

2.Select Go to URL. An additional section appears in the dialog box for this option.

3.In Select URL, in expression that evaluates to a URL, in pasted my pages url and concatenated it with field value in the below manner.
     http://localhost:64970/InvoiceManagement.aspx?a=Fields!INVOICE_NUMBER.Value
Click OK.
```

but on running report and clicking on the hyperlink, it redirects me well but in querystring i got **Fields!INVOICE_NUMBER.Value**, it doesnt get replaced by its value(database value which is int), which should be the Invoice number.

where I am  going wrong..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your field is being evaluated as a literal string. You need to write a function to generate the URL:

`="http://localhost:64970/InvoiceManagement.aspx?a=" & Fields!INVOICE_NUMBER.Value`

There should be a function box for URL target you can click in the properties dialog, or you could paste the function code in over your URL's text. Note: I'm using VS to manage my SSRS reports, and I'm unsure if these methods are the same for BIDS, if that's what you're using. The problem is the same either way, though.